# Named entity recognization using multiple lines using Spacy NLP

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy, named-entity-recognition

In Spacy NLP, I am not able to get exact output for named entity. My string value is on multiple lines. Please check below code:

```
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
m = (u"""Release the container 6th August

USG11223
USG12224
USG21113""")

doc = nlp(m)
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

OUTPUT: `[('6th August', 'DATE')]`

But i want output like

`['USG11223', 'USG12224', 'USG21113',6th August]`

Comment: The output for me is: ``[('6th', 'ORDINAL'), ('August', 'DATE')]`` But anyway, ``USG11223`` is not an entity. What exactly do you want as output? because with your current code your output is always going to be a list of tuples which doesn't match want you want

Answer (score 2):

One thing that most people do not realize about Named Entity Recognition in libraries like Spacy, AllenNLP, etc, is that it is usually a *Machine Learning model* trained on a **general corpus** for general entities.

Your data is from a **specific context**, where strings like "USG11223" have some special meaning. However, in general context, your string is no more than a random combination of letters and numbers and might even be discarded by the model preprocessing.

If you want the NER to recognize your tags as entities, *you can train your own model* to be able to recognize these tokens as entities, but you would have to provide several examples. You can learn more about how to do it here: https://spacy.io/usage/training/